# Neighborhood near $0$ for a sequence of non-negative measurable functions can be made arbitrarily small in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am doing some practice exercises from Avner's FoMA (2.4.1 to be precise). And encountered the following:

Let $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of a.e. real-valued, measurable functions that is convergent a.e. to $f$, and let $f\neq 0$ a.e., $f_n\neq 0$ a.e. $\forall n$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ $\exists$ $b>0$ and a measurable set $E_n$ such that $|f_n(x)|\geq b$ on $E_n$, and $\mu(E^c_n)<\epsilon$. [Hint prove the assertion first for f.]

What puzzles me is the hint. since $f_n$ share the properties of $f$, doesn't it follow if I simply prove it for $f$? Anyway, I gave it a go below and I'd like some feedback on whether it went wrong or not, and if, what? Thanks in advance!

*Proof for f.* Let $f$ be measurable and let $f\neq 0$ a.e.. Suppose there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $b>0$, $E_b=\{x \in X; |f(x)|\geq b >0\}$, $\mu(E_b^c)\geq \epsilon$. Now write 
$$E_b^c=\{x\in X; b>|f(x)|\geq 0\}=\{x\in X; b>|f(x)|> 0\}\cup \{x\in X; |f(x)|= 0\}\equiv A_b\cup B.$$
By assumption $\mu(B)=0$, so we now need to show that there exists $b>0$ such that $\mu(A_b)$ can be made arbitrarily small. Now set $b=1/n$, then $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$. Now by C1.2.3F
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(A_n)=\mu(\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n)=\mu(\emptyset).$$
Which precisely means that there exists $b=1/n$ such that $\mu(A_b)<\epsilon$ and we have our contradiction.

Since all the $f_n\neq 0$ a.e. and are measurable the result follows.

Comment: Are you sure that the wanted $E_n$ is not actually $E$ (which should not depend on $n$)?

Comment: I.e. a set $E$ such that it holds for all the $f_n$? I guess that would make sense. I double-checked though so I haven't copied the exercise wrong at least! But you do agree that the exercise as it stands is strange?

Do you know if your suggested alteration is true? If so, I will try to prove that instead.

Comment: I believe it is true, using Egoroff's theorem. I let you try.

Comment: Thanks! I will update with a solution (hopefully).

Comment: Any progress? (you can post an answer it you have a solution)

Comment: I'm afraid not, I have another unrelated deadline in a few days so havent had time to work on this.